# Set sibling DIV the equal height (tallest)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set paired divs the same height.

```
<div class="item ">
Some text
</div>
<div class="item right">
Some text
</div>
<div class="item ">
Some text<br/>Some text<br/>Some text<br/>Some text<br/>Some text
</div>
<div class="item right">
Some text<br/>Some text<br/>Some text<br/>Some text
</div>
<div class="item ">
Some text
</div>
<div class="item right">
Some text<br/>Some text<br/>Some text
</div>
```

css

```
.item{width: 45%;float: left;position: relative;border: 1px solid #000;clear:left;}
.item.right{float:right;clear:right;}
```

jQuery I'm using

```
$('.item.right').prev().each(function() {
    leftheight = $(this).height();
    rightheight = $(this).next().height();      
    if(leftheight > rightheight){
        $(this).next().height(leftheight);
    }else{
        $(this).height(rightheight);
    }               
});
```

This doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

I have two column layout where the divs have a pin line border, so it is very obvious when they are not the same height. the 'right class' float the item to the right.
I only want the pairs the same heights as they will form a row. I don't want to use tables (css or otherwise) as the layout is dynamic for mobile (where they form a single column).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `map()` to get the heights of the `div` left/right elements in to an array, then `Math.max` on the array to get the tallest, and use that value for both of them. Try this:

```
$('.item.right').each(function() {
    var $divs = $(this).add($(this).prev('.item'));
    var tallestHeight = $divs.map(function(i, el) {
        return $(el).height();
    }).get();
    $divs.height(Math.max.apply(this, tallestHeight));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hJA2y/)

Comment: this is the better answer than mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this(*`.map() and Math.max.apply()`*):

You have to get the heights in the array and look for the maximum value in the array then `Math.max.apply()` will apply the max value from the array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var heightArray = $(".item").map(function() {
        return  $(this).height();
   }).get();
   var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heightArray);
   $(".item").height(maxHeight);
});
```

[**Tryout the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ar5a/)

Answer (score 2):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/nTFtn/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/6tU2m/

Is this what you looking for!

Hope this helps `:)`

**code**

```
$('.item.right').prev('div').each(function () {

    leftheight = $(this).height();
    alert(leftheight);
    rightheight = $(this).next().height();
    if (leftheight > rightheight) {

        $(this).next().height(leftheight);
    } else {
        $(this).height(rightheight);
    }
});
```

Comment: is the addition of prev('div') the only change you made to my code .. was that all that was missing?

Comment: @Elijha `:)` Indeed bruv, by the looks of it `:))` rest you had the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first retrieve the max height, and then set all height to this one.

Like this :

```
var max_height = 0;
$('.item.right').prev().each(function() {
  if($(this).height() > max_height) {
     max_height = $(this).height();
  }
});
$('.item.right').prev().each(function() {
    $(this).height(max_height);
}
```

**EDIT**

So the error is on `next()` because you are already on the right item, and you compare with the `next()` one... Use `prev()` instead!

```
$('.item.right').prev().each(function() {
rightheight = $(this).height();
leftheight = $(this).prev().height();      
if(rightheight > leftheight){
    $(this).prev().height(rightheight);
}else{
    $(this).height(leftheight);
}               
});
```

Comment: I don't want to set ALL heights the same.. just the pairs for each row.

Comment: You get an up vote for telling me what I was missing - but the answer from Rory seems more efficient and flexible.